# How do you open a file using python, split rows into lists and then search for the row with the highest value in the third list

Tags: python, list, split

My script wont work, any suggestions appreciated...

The .txt file has 30 rows of data containing first name, second name, and a test mark which is a double digit number...

```
file = open ("testmarks.txt", "r")

for i in file:
    list = i.split()

#Get highest mark and print name

for(i) in list[2]:
    max_value = max(i)
    print('Highest mark was', max_value, 'achieved by', list[0], list[1])
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
input_file = open ("testmarks.txt", "r")

lists = [row.split() for row in input_file.readlines()]

lists = sorted(lists, key=lambda row: row[2], reverse=True)

print(f'Highest mark was {lists[0][2]} achieved by {lists[0][0]} {lists[0][1]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what I understand from your question and the text file looking like below,
I wrote the function below.

```
"""
aaa abc 100
bbb xyz 90
ccc def 80
"""


def sort_on_test_mark(file):

    with open(file, "r") as f:
        test_mark_list = []
        for idx, line in enumerate(f):
            # print(idx)
            # print(line)
            l = line.split()
            # print(l)
            test_mark_list.append(l)
    test_mark_list.sort(key=lambda x : int(x[-1]), reverse=True)
    first_name = test_mark_list[0][0]
    last_name = test_mark_list[0][1]
    max_value = int(test_mark_list[0][-1])
    return max_value, first_name+last_name

# file_path of your text file
result, name = sort_on_test_mark(file_path)
```